# USB devices don't work after restoring from Stand By

Tags: windows-xp, usb, standby

I'm running Windows XP SP3 on a NEC Versa L1100 laptop.

If I wake my laptop up from Stand By, no attached USB devices will function.

Device Manager shows all USB entries to be working properly.  There is an option to "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the Power Management properties of USB entries.

Is this causing the issue or something else?

I have the latest drivers for my motherboard installed.

Comment: "There is an option to "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the Power Management properties of USB entries" - Have you tried changing this option to see if it cures the problem, as it seems plausible?

Comment: I've since experienced the USB *working* after restoring from Stand By, and this setting has not been changed...